# integrate sapui5 application as a component

Tags: sapui5

I have a SapUI5 application that contains several views in a single page.

I want to convert that application in to a component so that it can be added to another project.  Is this possible, and does anyone have an idea how to do it?

I researched about components but I did not find anything that made it clear what I had to do.  I am grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, as a best practice your ui5 app should have been implemented as a component based app from the beginning. Then reusing such a component based app should work easily. I think you should have a look at the official [walkthrough tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) where you will learn a little about components. Then you could google for some blogs about components, maybe [my recent tutorial about components](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/implementing-re-use-components-in-sapui5-libraries-and-consuming-them-in-sapui5-apps) helps you as well. My tutorial tells you how to implement a component inside a library and reuse it then in apps (some new ui5 features related to components are discussed as well, i.e. usages).

And in case you only expected a simple answer to your question: test, it’s possible. See links above :-)

Comment: Hi Nabi, thank you for your prompt response.
The application starts without knowing the components, it would be perfect to do what you say, and now the need arises to use that application in different projects

Comment: So you have an app which you want to reuse in other projects/apps. Anyways, I’d suggest to go for components either in libs or even without lib. I believe the links mentioned contain everything needed. Just make sure you deploy your apps/components/libs correctly, then things should work fine. Again, have a detailed look into the links.